# Shoutem - Add location permission in custom extension

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, location, shoutem

I'm working on **Shoutem application**, I created a **custom extension** for display restaurants listing nearby user current location.

It's required **"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"** location, So I follow the step as per Shoutem document. (App segment)

https://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-native-project#app-segment

And copied the complete android and iOS directory from `shoutem.places` extension and rename the file and directory name as per my extension name.

But still I'm getting this error.

`Looks like the app doesn't have the permission to access location`

https://ibb.co/jDBZ5N1

**1. How can I get the permissions in my custom extension ?**

And

**2. what will be the package name of my custom extension at AndroidManifest.xml file?**

AndroidManifest.xml file in my custom extension.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chrsitian.restaurants">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: use runtime permissions to ask the user to provide your app location permission

Comment: Yeah, that is an option. But it is not a proper way to ask permission, I want to know the exact way how shoutem ask permission.